# Jquery Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to search for a particular pattern in my SQL , so that it starts only with SELECT and not with INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE.

How can i achieve this using JQuery , I would like to use JQuery to do a case insensitive matching of the string.

**EDIT**

I would also like to consider subqueries also.

Therefore my requirement is that the query should not contain any INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE statements anywhere. 
It should contain only SELECT statments

Comment: FYI, regular expressions are part of javascript. jQuery would not be required here.

Comment: Can you be more specific? jQuery is a big library, Regular expressions is a broad topic, "case-insensitive" is just an option for a RegExp. What real problem are you encountering?

Comment: ok, but how can i achieve it by either using Javscript or JQuery

Comment: @RobW
what I basically want to achieve , is validating a String to check that it does not contain any INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE statements and only SELECT statements

So essentially I want that the String should start with SELECT only , and rather then comparing it like a text , would like to use regular expression to validate it. So that incase if the user enters "select" , "Select" , "SELECT" etc etc.. it would all be valid

Comment: regex = /[select]/i;
result = regex.test(query);
if(result) { valid case }
else {invalid case }

Comment: @wannabeApro: That regex is unspeakably broken.

Comment: @Vivek: What about trailing whitespace, subqueries etc. Do you want to allow these? What exactly do you want to allow?

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark
Well. that is a good question. Yes. I would also like to consider subqueries. 
Infact i'll modify my question to the INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE statements cannot be present anywhere in the query. It should have only SELECT statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use a whitelist for that, rather than a blacklist:

```
function isValidQuery(str) {
  return /^select\s+([a-z_*]+,?)+\s+from\s+[a-z_]+$/i.test(str);
}
```

This only matches queries of the form `SELECT field, [field, ...] FROM table`. This can also be extended to allow certain kinds of `WHERE` or `GROUP BY` specifiers. If this isn't enough, you could also use a much stricter blacklist:

```
function isValidQuery(str) {
  if (/delete|update|insert|truncate|create|drop/i.test(str)) return false;
  // possibly more excluding rules...
  return true;
}
```

If you want to protect your data with this, I certainly wouldn't rely on the second method, as it can probably be circumvented (you forgot a dangerous command, SQL smuggling, ...) A *much* better approach would be to create a dedicated database user that only has read access to the tables you want to be available via this interface.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following:

```
function isSelect(str) {
    return /^select/i.test(str) && !/insert|update|delete.*/.test(str);
}

isSelect("select * from foo"); // true
isSelect("SELECT id, name from foo");  // true
isSelect("update ..."); // false
isSelect("DELETE ..."); // false
```

Comment: Thanks .. this worked. But coming to the question that Niklas asked, how can i modify the regex to that the query will not contain an UPDATE , DELETE , INSERT any where in the sql. 
It should contain only SELECT statements.

Comment: Glad the helped :-) I'd probably just add additional checks in the `isSelect()` function. Have updated my answer.

Comment: @jakeclarkson: If OP wants to protect data with this, I don't think your code is a good advise. For example, it allows the `drop` or `truncate` statements, as well as constructive statements like `create table`. Even if you add these to your blacklist, it can probably be circumvented (SQL smuggling, etc.). A better advise would be to use a *whitelist* instead and (additionally) use the DB-internal permissions mechanism to only allow reading access to certain tables.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark agreed. Your answer looks good :) I'll leave mine so people can see your comment and reasons why one might want to consider a different approach.